# How to store HTML tags into DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, tinymce

I'm using `Tiny Mce Editor 4.0.5` in `Rails 2`.
**new.html**

```
<% form_for @custom, :url=>"create" do |c| -%>
  <%= c.text_area 'description' %>
  <%= c.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Create Action:**

```
CustomReport.create(params[:custom_report][:description])
```

After submission of form I get

[image]

undefined method `stringify_keys!'

Along that I tried

```
CustomReport.create(:description => params[:custom_report][:description])
```

But it doesn't store any HTML tags, so how I can store tags along to my DB?

Comment: what is your field 'description'  type in database ??

Comment: description type is string.

Comment: please make it text and use `params[:custom_report][:description].html_safe`

Comment: thank you, but it didn't solve same error.

Comment: did you use `mysql`? if not then it will be a problem otherwise it is not a problem whether it is html or any thing as mysql save

Comment: got it it should be `CustomReport.create(:description => params[:custom_report][:description])`

Comment: This error is coming from a controller inside `vendor/plugins`. See the documentation of the plugin, for what parameters it accepts for create. May be there are some mandatory fields other than `description`

Comment: Also I have told above, it doesn't store HTML tags into db.

Comment: Can you tell what is the field type of description in database?

Comment: type is text currently, I've tried with varchar i.e string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [xss_terminate](https://github.com/jasherai/xss_terminate) plugin

And in my model `CustomReport`

> xss_terminate :except => [:description]

easy and simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
CustomReport.create(:description => params[:custom_report][:description])
```

should do the job for you, but Rails would naturally escape html tags, to stop rails from doing that you would need to call:

```
[html_safe](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe)
```

or

[raw](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw)

in your view on the string with the html tags (This is not safe practice, you should be sure the string is sincerely safe before considering this, as it can expose your app to attacks)