# how to insert sql timestamp value into datetime type in rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

```
date = Date.today     
query = "insert into custom_reports(name,description,created_at) values(#{report_name}, #{report_content}, #{date})"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query);
```

it inserts

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

So thought of going the mysql timestamp way. Is it possible to do?

Comment: check the db and the field type.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
query = "insert into custom_reports(name,description,created_at) values('#{report_name}', '#{report_content}', '#{Time.now}')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, changing

```
date = Date.today
```

to

```
date = Time.now
```

Apart from the above I tend to not use variables that may or may not accidentally be a `keyword` (especially when I am not sure), so instead of naming variable as `date`, I would use `d`

Comment: 2013-09-12 00:00:00 stores just the date, when used Date.today.

Comment: What's your db column type? Is it Date or DateTime?

Comment: Field name - created_at, Type - datetime

Comment: I can't read stuff like `date = Time.now`.  Either it's a time or it's a date.  Also, `Time.current` would cover more edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you write that SQL manually? Thats is more complicated and insecure, because you do not escape the strings in the query. On the other side `ActiveRecord` will take care of the `created_at` column.

I would prefer to have a basic model for that:

```
class CustomReport < ActiveRecord::Base
end

CustomRepor.create!(name: report_name, description: report_content)
```

Comment: I agree with you, but [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567089/how-to-store-html-tags-into-db) this wasn't solved, so I had to write using mysql manually.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql "Date" type columns should use

```
Date.now
```

Mysql "Time" type columns should use

```
Time.now
```

Mysql "DateTime" type columns have to use

```
DateTime.now
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I had to find out what is the data format on my `created_at` field

   ```
   rails db
   select created_at from users;

   +---------------------+
   | created_at          |
   +---------------------+
   | 2017-12-12 00:51:19 |
   | 2017-12-12 00:51:20 |
   | 2017-12-12 00:51:22 |
   | 2017-12-12 00:51:23 |
   +---------------------+
   ```
2. Then I have to run the raw query according to the format I'm using.

   ```
   date = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

   query = "insert into custom_reports(name,description,created_at) values(#{report_name}, #{report_content}, #{date})"
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try Changing the timestamp to date time format:

```
Time.at(1335437221)
```

convert
    2012-04-26 12:47:01 +0200