# Rails - Model Validations doesn't apply on mysql insert/update command

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, validation

For the [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567089/how-to-store-html-tags-into-db), I've used mysql cmd 
`insert into table_name (....)` 
`update custom_reports ...`
and hence I miss out on `Model validations`

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name
validates_presence_of :name, :description
```

> How to validate now in rails way? Or, use the mysql way to validate(needs help in this way too)?

Answer (score 1):

Rails validation and other `ActiveRecord` and `ActiveModel` magic don't work if you only execute custom SQL command. None of your model classes is even instantized then.

Answer (score 0):

For Mysql (or any sql like DB), you can modify the column attribute to:

- [Unique](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) (this would validate uniqueness)
- [Not null](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) (this would validate presence)

I know doing the above with OCI8 and oracle would result in exceptions which I am guessing should be same with ActiveRecord and Mysql, so you should be handling your exceptions correctly

But as @Marek as said you should be relying on Active record and be doing things like

`Model.create()

OR
model_instance.save()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find (and perhaps handle) the entries in your db that are not valid, try the following in the rails console:

```
ModelName.find_each do |item|
  unless item.valid?
    puts "Item ##{item.id} is invalid"
    # code to fix the problem... 
  end
end
```

`valid?` runs the `Validations` again, but does not alter the data.