# In tinymce entered value is posted as plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce

Hi i developed a ruby on rails application for conduction online MCQ exam. In that i use tinymce_hammer to add questions and answers. When i created a questions what is given is added into a database as plain text. how could i rectify it.

Here is the parameter for adding questions

```
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Ôû║ Create", "action"=>"create", "batch_id"=>"1", "aut
henticity_token"=>"bqFT9aAXHon8eV64QjirL0wM8ZuBy3JTyPuTT1vIRqE=", "module_id"=>"
1", "exam_group_id"=>"1", "controller"=>"questions", "question"=>{"ques"=>"<p>ds
af<sub>asdfasa</sub><sup>afddfaf</sup></p>", "ans1"=>"<p>asd</p>", "ans2"=>"<p>a
sdsdf</p>", "passage"=>"", "ans3"=>"<p>asd</p>", "ans4"=>"<p>f</p>"}, "is_answer
"=>"ans1"}
```

that is

ques=>

dsaf<sub>asdfasa</sub><sup>afddfaf</sup>

", "ans1"=>"

asd

", "ans2"=>"

a
sdsdf

", "passage"=>"", "ans3"=>"

asd

", "ans4"=>"

f

"}, "is_answer
"=>"ans1"}

But in same it insert as a plain text value as

```
  ←[4;36;1mQuestion Create (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mINSERT INTO `questions` (`ques`,
```

`ans1`, `ans2`, `passage`, `ans3`, `student_additional_field_id`, `exam_group_id`
, `ans4`, `is_answer`, `is_pass`) VALUES('dsafasdfasaafddfaf', 'asd', 'asdsdf',
 '', 'asd', 1, 1, 'f', 'ans1', '')←[0m

Please help me out

Comment: what is the type of `ques` and rails `-v`?

Comment: ques, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4 datatype is text rails version is 2.3.5

Comment: check my answer below, you can use https://github.com/jasherai/xss_terminate plugin, I had same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567089/how-to-store-html-tags-into-db) may help you, if you are on rails 3 or 4.

**Field type** should be `text` for those which contain `html tags`.

Understanding about [html_safe](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) and [raw](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw) would make things easier while dealing with `tags`